# MEAN stack app not working on Ubuntu (works in local)

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have developed a simple MEAN stack app (with Angular 4 for UI). 
It works fine in my local Node, but when I deploy the same on Ubuntu it gives

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <** : in browser console

Here is my app.js content

```
const app = express();

const users = require('./routes/users');
const client = require('./routes/client');

// Port Number
//const port = 3000;
// Port Number
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/client', client);

// Index Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Invalid Endpoint');
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});

// Start Server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port '+port);
});
```

My index.html under public folder

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MEAN</title>
  <base href=".">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <!--Bootstrap and jQuery online links-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- For login Html -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/icons/simple-line-icons.css">


</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing all cache? Have you made sure the files have the right permissions for your server to access?

Comment: I was only talking about your local browser cache, If you look in the network tab in your browser, can you see the requests going out for the correct files in the correct locations?

Comment: @OArnarsson - yes I tried this, but same issue, I can see that script/js  files are getting loaded (status : 200). where as in console I get this :inline.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
polyfills.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
styles.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
vendor.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
main.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: It's probably because you angular cannot find the files. Did you deploy your app on a sub folder, or is it at the root location?

Comment: @David - my app.js and 'public' folder at same level and under public folder index.html and other js files are at same level

Comment: in browser network console, shows all js files loaded (status : 200 ), but When I click on js files on js file, it opens index.html showing first line underlined as error!

Comment: Try adding that app.get('*.*', express.static(join(__dirname, 'public'))); before the index route

Comment: @David - tried, same issue, I am not getting why the js files are loading as type html

Comment: @Venkat: Are they loaded as html, or is the contetn for these js files the actual content of index.html? (when you open the response for the js requests in network tab)

Comment: @David, yes correct, the content for js files loading the actual content of index.html in the network tab

Answer (score 0):

Try changing: `'public'` to: `'/public'`, maybe the relative path helps?

Comment: :( No luck with '/public' -- path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html') gives the correct path when I printed it